# nexus pentaho unavailable?

Tags: maven, pentaho, mvn-repo

In my pom I have this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.pentaho.reporting.engine</groupId>
    <artifactId>classic-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.0.0-290</version>
</dependency>
```

available at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pentaho.reporting.engine/classic-core/9.2.0.0-290

But https://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/ is unaivailable

How should I do to install?

Answer (score 1):

I found this one in a forum:

https://repo.orl.eng.hitachivantara.com/ui/native/pnt-mvn/

I don't know if it's offical or not, but seems quite up to date.

Regards

Comment: As of 15 Feb 2024, the service seems to be down. Hope it is restored.